# Ubiquity frontend installer for Unity

Tags: unity, ubiquity, custom-installer

I want to place an installer on my Ubuntu 12.04 LiveCD, but now I'm confused. There are only 2 ubiquity-frontend packages:

- `ubiquity-frontend-gtk`
- `ubiquity-frontend-kde`

But not one for Unity.

Is it possible to use gtk package with Unity or how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gtk` package is what is used for the vanilla Unity Ubuntu installer. So yes, `ubiquity-frontend-gtk` would work fine.

Unity is basically a frontend or a shell to gtk3, much like Gnome Shell is.